# Can multiple .gz files be combined such that they extract into a single file?

Tags: linux, unix, gzip

Lets say that I have 3 file: `1.txt`, `2.txt` and `3.txt` which have all be gzipped.  I'm aware that gzip allows multiple files to be combined using cat:

```
cat 1.gz 2.gz 3.gz > 123.gz
```

However when 123.gz is extracted it will produce the original 3 files.

Is it possible to combine the three archives in a way that the individual files within the archive will be combined into a single file as well?

Comment: the traditional Unix way is to tar them. AFAIK [xz](http://tukaani.org/xz/) can do what you want, but those ain't zips.

Comment: When 123.gz is extracted by what?  gunzip _will_ extract that to a single file named 123.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Surprisingly, this is actually possible.

The [GNU zip man page states](http://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/manual/gzip.html#Advanced-usage): multiple compressed files can be concatenated. In this case, gunzip will extract all members at once.

**Example:**

You can build the zip like this:

```
echo 1 > 1.txt ; echo 2 > 2.txt; echo 3 > 3.txt;
gzip 1.txt; gzip 2.txt; gzip 3.txt;
cat 1.txt.gz 2.txt.gz 3.txt.gz > all.gz
```

Then extract it:

```
gunzip -c all.gz > all.txt
```

The contents of `all.txt` should now be:

```
1
2
3
```

Which is the same as:

```
cat 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

And - as you requested - "gunzip will extract all members at once".

Answer (score 4):

In order to concatenate multiple files, try:

```
gzip -c 1.txt > 123.gz
gzip -c 2.txt >> 123.gz
gzip -c 3.txt >> 123.gz
```

Subsequently, `gzip -dc 123.gz` would be equivalent to `cat 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't quite work in my case as each archive is written by a different reducer in a Hadoop job.