# how to concatenate zipped csv files without repeating the headers with shell

Tags: bash, shell, gzip

I have a folder with a lot of `gz` files.

```
out_batch_100_start_1477252800_end_1477256400_.gz
out_batch_101_start_1477256400_end_1477260000_.gz
out_batch_102_start_1477260000_end_1477263600_.gz
out_batch_103_start_1477263600_end_1477267200_.gz
out_batch_104_start_1477267200_end_1477270800_.gz
out_batch_105_start_1477270800_end_1477274400_.gz
out_batch_106_start_1477274400_end_1477278000_.gz
out_batch_107_start_1477278000_end_1477281600_.gz
out_batch_108_start_1477281600_end_1477285200_.gz
out_batch_109_start_1477285200_end_1477288800_.gz
out_batch_10_start_1476928800_end_1476932400_.gz
out_batch_110_start_1477288800_end_1477292400_.gz
out_batch_111_start_1477292400_end_1477296000_.gz
out_batch_112_start_1477296000_end_1477299600_.gz
out_batch_113_start_1477299600_end_1477303200_.gz
out_batch_114_start_1477303200_end_1477306800_.gz
out_batch_115_start_1477306800_end_1477310400_.gz
out_batch_116_start_1477310400_end_1477314000_.gz
out_batch_117_start_1477314000_end_1477317600_.gz
out_batch_118_start_1477317600_end_1477321200_.gz
out_batch_119_start_1477321200_end_1477324800_.gz
out_batch_11_start_1476932400_end_1476936000_.gz
out_batch_120_start_1477324800_end_1477328400_.gz
out_batch_121_start_1477328400_end_1477332000_.gz
out_batch_122_start_1477332000_end_1477335600_.gz
out_batch_123_start_1477335600_end_1477339200_.gz
out_batch_124_start_1477339200_end_1477342800_.gz
out_batch_125_start_1477342800_end_1477346400_.gz
out_batch_126_start_1477346400_end_1477350000_.gz
out_batch_127_start_1477350000_end_1477353600_.gz
out_batch_128_start_1477353600_end_1477357200_.gz
out_batch_129_start_1477357200_end_1477360800_.gz
out_batch_12_start_1476936000_end_1476939600_.gz
out_batch_130_start_1477360800_end_1477364400_.gz
out_batch_131_start_1477364400_end_1477368000_.gz
out_batch_132_start_1477368000_end_1477371600_.gz
out_batch_133_start_1477371600_end_1477375200_.gz
out_batch_134_start_1477375200_end_1477378800_.gz
out_batch_135_start_1477378800_end_1477382400_.gz
out_batch_136_start_1477382400_end_1477386000_.gz
out_batch_137_start_1477386000_end_1477389600_.gz
out_batch_138_start_1477389600_end_1477393200_.gz
out_batch_139_start_1477393200_end_1477396800_.gz
out_batch_13_start_1476939600_end_1476943200_.gz
out_batch_140_start_1477396800_end_1477400400_.gz
out_batch_141_start_1477400400_end_1477404000_.gz
out_batch_142_start_1477404000_end_1477407600_.gz
out_batch_143_start_1477407600_end_1477411200_.gz
out_batch_144_start_1477411200_end_1477414800_.gz
out_batch_145_start_1477414800_end_1477418400_.gz
out_batch_146_start_1477418400_end_1477422000_.gz
out_batch_147_start_1477422000_end_1477425600_.gz
out_batch_148_start_1477425600_end_1477429200_.gz
out_batch_149_start_1477429200_end_1477432800_.gz
out_batch_14_start_1476943200_end_1476946800_.gz
out_batch_150_start_1477432800_end_1477436400_.gz
out_batch_151_start_1477436400_end_1477440000_.gz
out_batch_152_start_1477440000_end_1477443600_.gz
out_batch_153_start_1477443600_end_1477447200_.gz
out_batch_154_start_1477447200_end_1477450800_.gz
out_batch_155_start_1477450800_end_1477454400_.gz
out_batch_156_start_1477454400_end_1477458000_.gz
out_batch_157_start_1477458000_end_1477461600_.gz
out_batch_158_start_1477461600_end_1477465200_.gz
out_batch_159_start_1477465200_end_1477468800_.gz
out_batch_15_start_1476946800_end_1476950400_.gz
out_batch_160_start_1477468800_end_1477472400_.gz
out_batch_161_start_1477472400_end_1477476000_.gz
out_batch_162_start_1477476000_end_1477479600_.gz
out_batch_163_start_1477479600_end_1477483200_.gz
out_batch_164_start_1477483200_end_1477486800_.gz
out_batch_165_start_1477486800_end_1477490400_.gz
out_batch_166_start_1477490400_end_1477494000_.gz
out_batch_167_start_1477494000_end_1477497600_.gz
out_batch_168_start_1477497600_end_1477501200_.gz
out_batch_16_start_1476950400_end_1476954000_.gz
out_batch_17_start_1476954000_end_1476957600_.gz
out_batch_18_start_1476957600_end_1476961200_.gz
out_batch_19_start_1476961200_end_1476964800_.gz
out_batch_1_start_1476896400_end_1476900000_.gz
out_batch_20_start_1476964800_end_1476968400_.gz
out_batch_21_start_1476968400_end_1476972000_.gz
out_batch_22_start_1476972000_end_1476975600_.gz
out_batch_23_start_1476975600_end_1476979200_.gz
out_batch_24_start_1476979200_end_1476982800_.gz
out_batch_25_start_1476982800_end_1476986400_.gz
out_batch_26_start_1476986400_end_1476990000_.gz
out_batch_27_start_1476990000_end_1476993600_.gz
out_batch_28_start_1476993600_end_1476997200_.gz
out_batch_29_start_1476997200_end_1477000800_.gz
out_batch_2_start_1476900000_end_1476903600_.gz
out_batch_30_start_1477000800_end_1477004400_.gz
out_batch_31_start_1477004400_end_1477008000_.gz
out_batch_32_start_1477008000_end_1477011600_.gz
out_batch_33_start_1477011600_end_1477015200_.gz
out_batch_34_start_1477015200_end_1477018800_.gz
out_batch_35_start_1477018800_end_1477022400_.gz
out_batch_36_start_1477022400_end_1477026000_.gz
out_batch_37_start_1477026000_end_1477029600_.gz
out_batch_38_start_1477029600_end_1477033200_.gz
out_batch_39_start_1477033200_end_1477036800_.gz
out_batch_3_start_1476903600_end_1476907200_.gz
out_batch_40_start_1477036800_end_1477040400_.gz
out_batch_41_start_1477040400_end_1477044000_.gz
out_batch_42_start_1477044000_end_1477047600_.gz
out_batch_43_start_1477047600_end_1477051200_.gz
out_batch_44_start_1477051200_end_1477054800_.gz
out_batch_45_start_1477054800_end_1477058400_.gz
out_batch_46_start_1477058400_end_1477062000_.gz
out_batch_47_start_1477062000_end_1477065600_.gz
out_batch_48_start_1477065600_end_1477069200_.gz
out_batch_49_start_1477069200_end_1477072800_.gz
out_batch_4_start_1476907200_end_1476910800_.gz
out_batch_50_start_1477072800_end_1477076400_.gz
out_batch_51_start_1477076400_end_1477080000_.gz
out_batch_52_start_1477080000_end_1477083600_.gz
out_batch_53_start_1477083600_end_1477087200_.gz
out_batch_54_start_1477087200_end_1477090800_.gz
out_batch_55_start_1477090800_end_1477094400_.gz
out_batch_56_start_1477094400_end_1477098000_.gz
out_batch_57_start_1477098000_end_1477101600_.gz
out_batch_58_start_1477101600_end_1477105200_.gz
out_batch_59_start_1477105200_end_1477108800_.gz
out_batch_5_start_1476910800_end_1476914400_.gz
out_batch_60_start_1477108800_end_1477112400_.gz
out_batch_61_start_1477112400_end_1477116000_.gz
out_batch_62_start_1477116000_end_1477119600_.gz
out_batch_63_start_1477119600_end_1477123200_.gz
out_batch_64_start_1477123200_end_1477126800_.gz
out_batch_65_start_1477126800_end_1477130400_.gz
out_batch_66_start_1477130400_end_1477134000_.gz
out_batch_67_start_1477134000_end_1477137600_.gz
out_batch_68_start_1477137600_end_1477141200_.gz
out_batch_69_start_1477141200_end_1477144800_.gz
out_batch_6_start_1476914400_end_1476918000_.gz
out_batch_70_start_1477144800_end_1477148400_.gz
out_batch_71_start_1477148400_end_1477152000_.gz
out_batch_72_start_1477152000_end_1477155600_.gz
out_batch_73_start_1477155600_end_1477159200_.gz
out_batch_74_start_1477159200_end_1477162800_.gz
out_batch_75_start_1477162800_end_1477166400_.gz
out_batch_76_start_1477166400_end_1477170000_.gz
out_batch_77_start_1477170000_end_1477173600_.gz
out_batch_78_start_1477173600_end_1477177200_.gz
out_batch_79_start_1477177200_end_1477180800_.gz
out_batch_7_start_1476918000_end_1476921600_.gz
out_batch_80_start_1477180800_end_1477184400_.gz
out_batch_81_start_1477184400_end_1477188000_.gz
out_batch_82_start_1477188000_end_1477191600_.gz
out_batch_83_start_1477191600_end_1477195200_.gz
out_batch_84_start_1477195200_end_1477198800_.gz
out_batch_85_start_1477198800_end_1477202400_.gz
out_batch_86_start_1477202400_end_1477206000_.gz
out_batch_87_start_1477206000_end_1477209600_.gz
out_batch_88_start_1477209600_end_1477213200_.gz
out_batch_89_start_1477213200_end_1477216800_.gz
out_batch_8_start_1476921600_end_1476925200_.gz
out_batch_90_start_1477216800_end_1477220400_.gz
out_batch_91_start_1477220400_end_1477224000_.gz
out_batch_92_start_1477224000_end_1477227600_.gz
out_batch_93_start_1477227600_end_1477231200_.gz
out_batch_94_start_1477231200_end_1477234800_.gz
out_batch_95_start_1477234800_end_1477238400_.gz
out_batch_96_start_1477238400_end_1477242000_.gz
out_batch_97_start_1477242000_end_1477245600_.gz
out_batch_98_start_1477245600_end_1477249200_.gz
out_batch_99_start_1477249200_end_1477252800_.gz
out_batch_9_start_1476925200_end_1476928800_.gz
```

I would like them to be concatenated in a single file.  Each gz starts with the same headers. I would then like to keep only headers on the top of the file.  In other words for all the `gz` except the first file the first line should be skipped.

How can I do that?

EDIT: 
One of the files:

```
(numeric_python) luca@luca-VirtualBox:~/Documents/datasets/RNDC/7days$ zcat out_batch_1_start_1476896400_end_1476900000_.gz | head
Protocol,Src,Src Port,Dst,Dst Port,Group ID,Port,VPort,IP TOS,VLAN ID,VLAN Pri,MPLS Exp,Application,Packets,Messages,Bytes,First,Last,"EmergingThreats category","EmergingThreats description","EmergingThreats detailedDescription","EmergingThreats first_seen","EmergingThreats last_seen","EmergingThreats ports","EmergingThreats score","Entity AD_SecurityGroup","Entity Privileged","Entity Unique_Users","Entity User","OS OS","STIX description","STIX detailedDescription","STIX timeStamp","iSIGHT ThreatScape","iSIGHT asn","iSIGHT domain","iSIGHT networkIdentifier","iSIGHT networkType","iSIGHT port","iSIGHT productType","iSIGHT publishDate","iSIGHT reportId","iSIGHT reportLink","iSIGHT title","iSIGHT webLink"
ETH:0x0000,00:17:A4:77:9C:04,,09:00:2B:00:00:05,,2,PortC,0,,,,,"Unknown",472,0,28320,1476896408,1476899995,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
ETH:0x0000,00:17:A4:77:9C:0A,,09:00:2B:00:00:04,,2,PortC,0,,,,,"Unknown",1938,0,125769,1476899771,1476899999,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
ETH:0x0000,00:17:A4:77:9C:0A,,09:00:2B:00:00:05,,2,PortC,0,,,,,"Unknown",498,0,29880,1476896400,1476899999,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
ETH:0x0000,00:26:F2:C1:00:00,,01:80:C2:00:00:00,,2,PortC,0,,,,,"Unknown",1801,0,108060,1476896401,1476899999,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
ETH:0x0000,00:26:F2:C6:00:00,,01:80:C2:00:00:00,,2,PortC,0,,,,,"Unknown",1801,0,108060,1476896401,1476899999,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
ETH:0x0000,00:26:F3:2A:00:00,,01:80:C2:00:00:00,,2,PortC,0,,,,,"Unknown",1801,0,108060,1476896401,1476899999,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
ETH:0x0000,00:26:F3:8C:00:00,,01:80:C2:00:00:00,,2,PortC,0,,,,,"Unknown",1801,0,108060,1476896401,1476899999,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
ETH:0x0000,00:30:6E:48:17:18,,09:00:09:00:00:01,,2,PortC,0,,,,,"Unknown",13,0,780,1476896412,1476899999,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
ETH:0x0000,84:78:AC:15:44:BC,,01:80:C2:00:00:00,,2,PortC,0,,,,,"Unknown",1801,0,108060,1476896401,1476899999,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
(numeric_python) luca@luca-VirtualBox:~/Documents/datasets/RNDC/7days$
```

Comment: decompress and then concatenate `head -1 any_file` and `tail -q -n +2 all_files`?

Comment: I can not decompress as they do not fit in the hard drive.  I need something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715484/can-multiple-gz-files-be-combined-such-that-they-extract-into-a-single-file but that skips the fist line and iterates over all the `gz`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following concatenates the files previously stripping off the first lines:

```
find out_batch_103_start_*.gz -exec sh -c "zcat -q -c {} | tail -n +2 -" \;
```

where `tail -n +2 -` outputs the lines read from the standard input (`-`) starting from the second line.

It is easy to prepend a header to the output:

```
zcat out_batch_100_start_1477252800_end_1477256400_.gz | head -1 > output
find out_batch_103_start_*.gz \
  -exec sh -c "zcat -q -c {} | tail -n +2 -" \; >> output
```

The result is written to the `output` file.

If you want to compress the output on-the-fly, then you should *group* the two commands:

```
{ zcat out_batch_100_start_1477252800_end_1477256400_.gz | head -1 && \
    find out_batch_103_start_*.gz \
      -exec sh -c "zcat -q -c {} | tail -n +2 -" \;
      } | gzip - > output.gz
```

where `{ }` creates a *group of commands* in Bash (see `info bash {`).

Comment: Just to be safe can you write the code such that the output is saved in `all_batches.gz`

Comment: @Donbeo, added a sample

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to check what file is beeing processed ? Like using `-v` somewhere in order to track the progresses.

Comment: @Donbeo, `zcat -v` (without `-q`) will print some kind of progress to `stderr`

Comment: IT seems to be working . It is processing the data. I'll remove the V if I encounter a problem but hopefully this is  working fine :)

Comment: @Donbeo, it will be fine. Alternative way is to out `printf >&2 '%q\n' {};` just before `zcat` in the command string

Comment: replace gzip with pigz for even more speed with multiple cores!